# How to force non-empty content element in XML Schema

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an XML Schema with an optional element. When this element occurs, I want to avoid an empty element. Is this possible in XML Schema?

Example:

```
  <xsd:complexType name="example">
    <xsd:simpleContent>
      <xsd:extension base="basetype>
      </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:simpleContent>
  </xsd:complexType>
```

How do I prevent this from happening:

```
<example />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can restrict its length:

```
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="baseType">
                    <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
```

This of course, working only for simple types. For complex types, you should make sure at least one of the nested elements is not optional.